# Using eclipse plug-in projects in a maven-plugin development

Tags: eclipse, build, maven-plugin, dependency-management

I am developing a **maven-plugin** in eclipse, at the beginning i had all classes in one eclipse project. As the requirements grew, i started to seperate different concerns (model, model generation, other logic) into different **"eclipse-pugin-projects"**, that are sharing their dependencies over manifest files.

Now i have different plugin-projects, that are partly used in other projects. I want to build a maven-plugin in one bundle, that needs dependencies to other bundles (model etc).

How can i build the maven-plugin and get the dependencies to other bundles?

I know about maven tycho, but i couldn't get information, if maven tycho can build a maven-plugin.

if i run the build now, which is in the one bundle with the mojo class, it (of course) cant find the classes that the project pulls over the manifest declaration.

**Project Structure**

As for now i have this three bundles/eclipse-plugin-projects:

**- model:** Contains the model.

**- model.generate:** reads data and generates model data.

**- generate.htmldoku:** uses generated model data to generate a documentation website. In this bundle is a mojo class, that is used in a maven-plugin.

Comment: Eclipse plug-ins are for Eclipse (or other OSGi platforms) only, not Maven.

Comment: Thank you, that answers my question, if this is at all possible. I think, the normal way would be using project dependency [like this](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-add-a-project-as-a-dependency-of-another-project.html)?